# Dual Boot Ubuntu Server Edition and Windows 7 Professional

Tags: server, dual-boot, windows-7

I've dual booted Ubuntu desktop edition with windows but id now like to dual boot Ubuntu Server Edition with Windows 7; I have Windows 7 installed on my laptop and I'd like to install ubuntu server edition so I can run my kannel gateway installation on it.

Is this possible? I havent seen articles on it anywhere ; And are there  restrictions/problems I should expect from this installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible and there won't be any problems. Essentially the server edition is just
like the desktop one, with different packages and some kernel optimization.

So, if the desktop works, there is absolutely no reason why the server shouldn't.
Even if it didn't work, you could just install/purge the differences in the desktop version

Comment: Hey, Thanks; I guess you never know the problems with the configuration unless you try it out.